# how to remove a Do-Not-Track-Me cookie that was set on an ipad?

Tags: cookies, matomo

I had an ipad, and i used its browser to manage my piwik system. so, to exclude my visits, i've set a do-not-track-me cookie, through the admin area.

I don't have that ipad anymore, but i want piwik to ignore the cookie, can it be done?

Comment: Cookies are per-browser; it doesn't exist in other browsers.

Comment: I know, that is why i wonder if i can distinct a certain coockie, and ignore it

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be on whatever new device you have (cookies are on a per-browser basis, which means a per-device basis).

However, if that's the case, either delete all cookies on your browser or run

```
javascript:void(document.cookie="Do-Not-Track-Me=");
```

replacing `Do-Not-Track-Me` with the name of the cookie (if it's different).